# How can I test AWS Lambda functions locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda

Explain to me please what is the best way to locally test the lambda function. I used sam local and this solution `https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda` for testing, but for example, where I invoke one lambda from another error occurs. In general, I can't make stubs for methods since lambda runs in a container

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are a couple of options. Following two are some popular ones.

- [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework along with the [serverless-offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline)
  plugin.
- [LocalStack](https://localstack.cloud/)

Comment: If you're looking for something very light, there are also a few npmjs packages that allow this (NodeJS), such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local

Answer (score 4):

For local manual testing (not unit testing) with `sam cli` you can specify the environment varilables file with the `-n, --env-vars PATH`option and use your real resource identifiers like you would normally do within your Cloud Formation template (refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke-environment-file) for more informations).

This should let you invoke other functions directly and use a real DynamoDB table and all other AWS Cloud resources.

Note: if you use VSCode you can try [this helper extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bogdan-onu.invoke).

Answer (score 4):

Adding here one more option, just because of the it's simplicity. You can download locally the AWS lambda runtime environment as described [in AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html)

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.aws-lambda-rie && curl -Lo ~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie \
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie \
&& chmod +x ~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie
```

To test the lambda function locally run you can then run on a terminal session:

```bash
~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie go run main.go
```

This will start a server listening on port 8080. To actually trigger the lambda function, you can finally run on another terminal session:

```bash
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"Name": "World"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I test local lambda functions without Serverless frameworks, I run an HTTP post on local (quite easy setup for Go)

- decouple lambda logic like so:

```
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    _, _ = pretty.Println("parsed:", request.Body)
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "response is working", StatusCode: 200}, nil
}
```

- main function then checks if it is a local instance then run local post endpoint, else start lambda

```
func main() {
    environment := loadEnv()
    if environment == "develop" {
        router.NewRouter()
        select {}
    } else {
        lambda.Start(lambdahandler.HandleRequest)
    }
}
```

- in between you have an Adapter Pattern that converts your http request to whatever your lambda function accepts, for example:

```
func MapToApiGateway(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, error) {
    request := new(EmailResponderRequest)
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(request); err != nil {
        return err.Error(), err
    }
    apiGatewayRequest := mapHttpRequestToGatewayRequest(*request)
    events, err := lambdahandler.HandleRequest(nil, apiGatewayRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error(), err
    }
    return events, nil
}
```