# How is it possible to debug an AWS Lambda function from remote?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

We are taking over a whole application from another company, and they have built the whole pipeline for deploying, but we still don't have access to it. What we know, that there's a lambda function is running triggered by certain SNS messages, and all the code is in Node.js, and the development is in VS Code. We also have issues debugging it locally, but it's a bigger problem, that we need to debug it remotely.

Since I am new in AWS services, I'd really appreciate if somebody could help me in this. 
Does it necessary to open a port? How is it possible to connect to a lambda? Do we need serverless to setup? Many unresolved questions.

Comment: You can't. There is no way to connect to a lambda for debugging. You can log and use X-Ray for tracing, but you cannot connect to the code while it is running.

Comment: As Jason said, you cannot connect to Lambda for debugging since there isn't a dedicated instance running that code. But you can trigger your Lambda function with test events and check its Cloudwatch logs to trace possible errors

Comment: Both @FábioPeresToi and Jason are inaccurate on their comments. You may want to refer to this post https://www.slappforge.com/blog/live-debug-your-aws-lambda-functions-in-nodejs and to this GitHub repo: https://github.com/trek10inc/aws-lambda-debugger
Yes, I know, it seems crazy but it is possible. Still, I think remote debugging is completely useless as one can usually fallback to other resources, but, well, it's possible.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth

Comment: Just in case anyone else goes down a rabbit hole trying to use AWS Toolkit for JetBrains for this purpose, I found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/run-debug-configurations-dialog-remote.html which states: "Although the name of the dialog box is Run/Debug Configurations, you cannot use the AWS Toolkit for JetBrains to debug the remote version of a Lambda function. You can only run the function."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is way you can debug a lambda function remotely. Your best bet is to download the code on local machine, setup the env variables as you have set up on your lambda function and take it from there.

Remember at the end of the day lambda is just a container which is running the code for you. AWS doesn't allow any ssh or connection with those container. In your case you should be able to debug it on local till you have the same env variables. There are other things as well which are lambda specific but considering it is a running code which you have got so you should be able to find out the issue.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I thought the same, then I just found [thundra](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thundra.thundra-debugger). I still thinking about it

Answer (score 3):

The way AWS have you 'remote' debug is to execute the lambda locally through Docker as it proxies the requests to the cloud for you, using AWS Toolkit. You have a lambda running on your local computer via docker that can access resources on the cloud, such as databases, api's etc. You can step through debug them using editors like vscode.

I use SAM with a template.yaml . This way, I can pass event data to the handler, reference dependency layers (shared code libraries) and have a deployment manifest to create a Cloudformation stack (release instance with history and resource management).

Debugging can be a bit slow as it compiles, deploys to Docker and invokes, but allows step through debugging and variable inspection.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html

Answer (score 2):

Thundra (https://www.thundra.io/aws-lambda-debugger) has live/remote debugging support for AWS Lambda through its native IDE plugins (VSCode and IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Thundra site gone, checked as of June 2023.

Answer (score 0):

While far from ideal, any console-printing actions would likely get logged to CloudWatch, which you could then access to go through printed data.

For local debugging, there are many Github projects with `Dockerfile`s which which you can build a docker container locally, just like AWS does when your Lambda is invoked.

Comment: If there are so many, would you mind sharing a few? :)

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127264/10761353